# Python: Computing matrices with arbitrary elements?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

How can I in python create and calculate solutions for matrices with arbitrary elements?

For example, let's say I want to create square matrix with elements: a,a,a,a and add it up to square matrix with elements: b,b,b,b.

The result should then be a+b for each element in the new matrix, as letters.

Other example, I multiply a matrix by scalar k and want the k's inside the matrix. I will receive an error if I don't specify exact value of k, but I want it to be arbitrarily valued and show up as "k".

Comment: Take a look at SymPy http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: as suggested by [PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring),  [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html) might be solution.

**other answer**:

I think [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started) might help you in this case.

Although, Writing equations might be slightly different in this case.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# define your variables before hand.
# tf.placeholder(<type of element>, <dimensions>)
arr1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2,2])
arr2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2,2])

# if it doesn't have dimension no need to mention.
scalar = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# these are your arrays which contain those arbitrary values you mentioned
multiplied_array = arr1*scalar
added_array = arr1+arr2
adding_to_multiplied = multiplied_array+arr1

# to evaluate these into any number, you need a session
sess = tf.Session()

# just provide values of arr1, scalar, arr2 to evaluate the results
print(sess.run(multiplied_array,{arr1:[[1,2],[3,4]],scalar:22}))
print(sess.run(added_array,{arr1:[[1,2],[3,4]],arr2:[[5,6],[7,8]]}))
print(sess.run(adding_to_multiplied,{arr1:[[1,2],[3,4]],arr2:[[5,6],[7,8]],scalar:22}))
```

Comment: Not quite, I would like to have the "k" inside the matrix. As if I was doing arbitrarily valued math problem on paper.

Comment: I've updated the answer. In this one, you can have arbitrary valued math equation and to evaluate, you need the provide the values.